# jQuery clueTip: original tooltip is shown together with the cluetip tooltip (2 tooltips)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, cluetip

I have a problem with the [jQuery clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip) plugin.

I'm initialize the plugin in this way:

```
$(function(){
    $("#contentTable > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        $(this).children("td:eq(3)").cluetip({
            splitTitle: '|',
            showTitle: false,
            escapeTitle: true,
            dropShadow: true,
            cursor: 'default',
            cluetipClass: 'info',
            positionBy: 'mouse',
            attribute: 'tooltip'
        });
    });
});
```

It is working, but after clicking and hovering a few times over my `td` elements, the `title` attribute is filled again and **the original tooltip is displayed together with the cluetip tooltip (in Internet Explorer)**.

Does anybody have an idea?

*Screenshots*

Page Load:

http://tinypic.com/r/vowexi/6

After clicking/hovering/acting:

http://tinypic.com/r/16j4ldi/6

I'm using *jQuery 1.7.2* and *cluetip 1.2.5*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to [simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/).

I have no such a problem with this plugin, so this will be my choice.